# Create a new SQL function fails with multiple errors using MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to add a new function to an existing MariaDB Database. This is the update script:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION second_diff(dateColA timestamp, dateColB timestamp) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE diff INT;
    if dateColB is null then
        SET diff = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, current_timestamp);
    else
        SET diff = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, dateColB);
    end if;
    RETURN diff;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

UPDATE version SET current_version = '1.0.1';
```

When I am running it, it fails with the following errors:

> Error executing: DELIMITER //
> CREATE FUNCTION second_diff(dateColA timestamp, dateColB timestamp) RETURNS INT
> BEGIN
> DECLARE diff INT
> .  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1720684) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
> else
> SET diff = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, dateColB)

> Error executing:     if dateColB is null then
> SET diff = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, current_timestamp)
> .  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: (conn=1720684) Unknown system variable 'diff'
> Error executing:     else
> SET diff = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, dateColB)
> .  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1720684) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'else
> end if

> Error executing:     end if
> .  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1720684) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'end if' at line 1
> RETURN diff

> Error executing:     RETURN diff
> .  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1720684) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN diff' at line 1
> END

> Error executing: END
> .  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1720684) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
> //
> DELIMITER

> Error executing: DELIMITER
> .  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1720684) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
> UPDATE version SET current_version = '1.0.1'

**EDIT:** This only fails when I am running this migration script at a different server. On my local machine everything is working fine. I was already checking the version numbers of both different MariaDBs. They are both the same.

Comment: The error messages are self-explanatory and helpful. Why aren't you following them?

Comment: @Dai I edited my post. This is working fine on my local machine but not on a development server.

Comment: What (Java) software do you use to execute the sql commands?

Comment: @theking2 On my local machine I am using flyway (this works). On the development server I am not sure what is used, since I am using a REST interface there for updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When running the migration script at the different server, mybatis was used to execute it. According to this [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/migrations/issues/49), you need a special syntax when using Delimiter. So instead of using

`DELIMITER //` and `DELIMITER ;`

it was necessary to write

`-- @DELIMITER //`and `-- @DELIMITER ;`